# Azure Logic App - how to get rows from an SQL function

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I've got an SQL database hosted in Azure, and a few Logic Apps that are pulling data from it (where you can search through a table or view) using the standard Get Rows method.

However, I now have to try to get data using a function in the SQL database, which (in the database) can be done using:

```
select * from dbo.GETDataByNumbers(-1.23,-4.56,7.89,10.1112)
```

How would I do that in the Logic App? I've got four numbers in the JSON which the user can specify (let's say n1, n2, n3, n4) and I need to feed these to the function and get the response.

I've currently got a "When a http request is received" set up, a "Get Rows" (which is where I'm stuck), and the "Response".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Execute a SQL query (V2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#execute-a-sql-query-(v2)) action instead of `Get Rows` action.

[image]

And your sql statement syntax should be like this:

```
select dbo.GETDataByNumbers(-1.23,-4.56,7.89,10.1112)
```

Comment: Nearly, I think. Running this, it thinks dbo should be a column. And if I use something like "select id, myname from dbo.GetDataByNumbers(-1.23,-4.56,7.89,10.1112)" it complains it isn't a valid json.

Comment: @user25730, When I run the sql you provided, an error will be reported. The example in the official document is written like this.

Comment: in actuality, it seems to be working now using "select id, myname from dbo.GetDataByNumbers(-1.23,-4.56,7.89,10.1112)". Don't know why. Go figure! Now I just need to figure out how to parameterise it and get the results how I want them! Thanks for your help, you certainly pointed me in the right direction.